# Unable to Import Variables using Go's "text/template" Library

Tags: go, go-templates

I have the following template files:

```
// main.tmpl
This is the main.                // line 1
{{ template "myFunc" }}          // line 2
{{- $name }}       // line 3
```

```
// helper.tmpl
This is a helper
{{- $name := "Nick" -}}

{{- define "myFunc" -}}
  Hello
{{- end -}}
```

And in [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/h6sE_5-hIP5);

```golang
package main

import (
  "text/template"
  "io/ioutil"
  "fmt"
  "bytes"

)

func main() {
    files := []string{"helper.tmpl", "main.tmpl"}
    t := template.New(files[0]).Funcs(make(map[string]interface{}))

    // Read the contents of each file, and parse it.
    // Couldn't get template.ParseFiles working, kept getting
    // "incomplete or empty template" errors.
    for _, file := range files {
        f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        t.Parse(string(f))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := t.Execute(&buf, make(map[string]string))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

When I run my main, keeping `main.tmpl` as is, the output is:

```
This is a helper.
```

However, when I run my main after deleting line 3 in `main.tmpl`, the output is:

```
This is the main.
Hello
```

---

Q: Why does calling a variable from `helper.tmpl` cause overwriting of `This is the main.`, and executing ignoring the rest of `main.tmpl`? It almost seems like the buffer is being overwritten. Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your "manual" parsing probably fails too. `t.Parse(string(f))` returns an error which you don't assign to `err`, you just "recheck" the `error` returned by reading the file.

Comment: Also note that if `$name` is defined in `helper.tmpl`, you can't access it from `main.tmpl`.

Comment: @icza good catch on the missing `err` assignment, I hadn't even realized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables

> A variable's scope extends to the "end" action of the control
> structure ("if", "with", or "range") in which it is declared, or to
> the **end of the template** if there is no such control structure. A
> template invocation does not inherit variables from the point of its
> invocation.

Comment: I was struggling with this for quite some time. I didn't realize that a variable's scope ended at the end of the template, and that they couldn't be "imported".